# Unable to fix - events.js:183 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

Tags: node.js, twitter, stream

I am using a Mac. I am trying to run a simple Twitter stream but I am getting the error `events.js:183 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event`. After some googling, it seems like this usually happens when there is already a node process running. I've restarted my computer, reopened the terminal and tried all sorts of different terminal commands.

`killall node` => `No matching processes belonging to you were found`

`killall -9 node` => `No matching processes belonging to you were found`

`ps aux | awk '/node/{print $2}' | xargs kill -9` => `kill: 872: No such process`

`rm -rf node_modules && npm cache clean --force` => doesn't work

```
const Twitter = require('twitter');

const twitter = new Twitter({
  consumer_key: '',
  consumer_secret: '',
  access_token: '',
  access_secret: ''
});

twitter.stream('filter', { track: 'hello' }, function(stream) {
  stream.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log(data.text);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values of `access_token` and `access_secret` were incorrect.
It wasn't a problem of a different node process already running.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is related to the NPM cache.
I've solved a similar problem running this commands in console as suggested in the post below.

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json yarn.lock
npm cache clear --force
npm install
```

https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/1072